# Outside of projection matrix? (OpenGL)

Tags: opengl, matrix, projection

Given a model-view-projection matrix, how would I determine if an object is displayed on the screen? Determining if it is within the clipping bounds is easy, but how do I use the numbers if the mvp matrix to determine if object is too far left/right/high/low given the object position and the screen width and height in pixels? (For simplicity, we can say that we only care about the object's center of mass)

Comment: Are you trying to implement frustum culling?

Comment: Its for a tessellation evaluation shader - I apply 0 level tessellation if the patch is outside of the viewer's view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simply apply the mvp matrixes to the center: `centerInScreen = projMartix*viewMatrix*modelMatrix*center`

then see if centerInScreen is inside the -1,-1 to 1,1 box, (which opengl maps to the viewport)

Comment: One additional condition actually remains: those coordinates are in *clip-space*, to test those coordinates the proper range for xyz is [**-w**,**w**]. You can either perform that test, or divide the coordinates by w; if you do the latter, then the range [**-1**,**1**] *(NDC)* you discussed applies.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: actually, you always will have to test before the divide. Otherwise, you will get false positives (of objects which actually lie behind the camera), or situations with division by 0.

Comment: @derhass I am not sure I follow. Division by **0.0** produces positive/negative infinity, which will fail the test.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: Remember that with a typical GL projection matrix, `w_clip`=`-z_eye`. You cannot realy do the division to get to NDC space for vertices which lie in the camera plane `z_eye=0`. But you can easily exclude them as outside the frustum in clip space, since the condition -0 < {x,y,z} < 0 will never be satisfied. But, that is just a side node. The bigger issue are IMHO vertices which lie behind the camera. Note that x/w == -x/-w, so the images of such vertices are just mirrored, but even the z coord is mirrored to end up in front of the camera.

Comment: @derhass I see what you mean. I was thinking in terms of vertices; vertices with w=0.0 in clip-space are clipped, but the test in this question is actually for visibility given the centroid of an object and not clipping.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: Actually, I oversimplified a bit in my last comment. The correct condition would be -0 <= {x,y,z} <= 0, which looks like it could be fulfilled for some vertices. And for x and y, it actually can. But the clip space z used here will always be != 0 for any vertex with z_eye=0 due to the construction of the matrix. Typycally `z_clip=A*z_eye+B`. `A` does not matter in this case, but `B` could only be `0` if the near or far plane were at distance 0.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: That has nothing to do with clipping itself. The test is just about if a clip space position vector lies inside or outside the viewing frustum. And just using the [-1,1]^3 NDC cube is not the correct mathematical description of the view frustum. Doing so implicitely assumes that such kind of clipping has happened before the divide.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54355/discussion-between-derhass-and-andon-m-coleman).